# Split string and add part on it

Tags: php, string, replace, split, preg-replace

So say that I have a string like `2x + 2y`, and I want to split these strings.

I want the split to be done and it will look like `2 * x + 2 * y` after it has been parsed or changes have been made to it.

I looked on the PHP Manual for `preg_replace` but I couldn't seem to find the right thing for me, I was thinking it might look for a `number + letter` then replace it using the `*` in the middle of it, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Use http://www.phpliveregex.com for regex testing

Comment: Just to get you started: `preg_replace("/([0-9]+)([A-Za-z])/", "$1 * $2", $str);`

Comment: using regexp may be a solution, but in m opinion quite difficult to use it in this context, read about tokenizing input - you just need to parse text split it to tokens, eg. "2x+2y" should be tokenized to: Number(2),Operator(multiply),Variable(x)Operator(sum)Number(2)Variable(y)
Then you can do whatever you want as the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

```
<?php
$string = "2x + 2y";
$result = preg_replace("/([0-9]+)([A-Za-z])/", "$1 * $2", $string);
echo $result;
?>
```